# How to create a out of div hover

Tags: html, css

wanna know is there a way to do this:

```
<div class="booth">
    <div class="part">Part 1</div>
    <div class="part">Part 2</div>
    <div class="part">Part 3</div>
    <div class="part">Part 4</div>
</div>
```

Using the :hover on css i expand the size of an inner div to a `height:100%` `width:100%` from the `.booth` class. I have the problem that the title of each part is visible over the full size.

it's difficult to explain...i know, and my english is not good....

Comment: Wouldn't increasing the size of a child, automatically increase the parent? Just don't give the .booth a size.

Comment: post the css part of your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think your taking about having either of the 4 div expand to the full size of the parent div and overlap the other child divs. I would try using the z-index property on the "part" class instead of the booth to resolve it.